# What is the usual timing of IM calculation (same day 4pm, COB, COB +x hours etc)? What is the range on the market?

Tags: isda-simm

Question as above regarding ISDA standard initial margin model. Are there any technical limitations to calculate margin for various risk classes (i.e. wait for end of tay trading book data)?

Comment: When we implemented the model, we used the EOD data where also used by risk. Best for reconciliation, no need to store two sets of data etc.

Comment: @Kermittfrog Thanks. Is the above specified anywhere ? I've looked into https://www.isda.org/a/owEDE/risk-data-standards-v1-36-public.pdf and https://www.isda.org/a/CeggE/ISDA-SIMM-v2.4-PUBLIC.pdf but found nothing worthwhile. ISDA has a nice open source CDS pricing tool (ISDA CDS standard model). Is there something similar for simm?

Comment: For non-commercial use, there is an implementation available here: https://github.com/AcadiaSoft/simm-lib. IMHO, you should try to match the timing of 'your' SIMM calculation as good as possible with the timing of your counterparty.